# Any WPF Gauge Controls that are open source?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to find an open source WPF Gauge Control that I can use in my Rich Client (not for silverlight).  Does anyone have any recommendations on one that is open source?

I need to build a WPF dashboard and the client is requesting using Gauges to display data.

Comment: Arction has free Gauges for WPF and Silverlight. Not open-source, but free to use and distribute, with several examples. See http://arction.com/products_arction_gauges

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Also, with the ArcSegment control and the RotateTransform transform, it shouldn't be that awful to roll your own

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/01/Mathematics-of-ArcSegment.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TransformationsIntro.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PieChartDataBinding.aspx

Comment: the NextWave WPF suite is trial-only  :(  Other links are great though!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:  http://dashboarding.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6):

**[Here is a CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/circulargaugecontrol.aspx)** page with some circular WPF and Silverlight gauges. They are licensed under the Free BSD license. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is a new WPF Gauge control on codeplex that looks pretty nice:
http://wpfgauge.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, wpfgauge at codeplex uses LGPL license, which makes it unfriendly to businesses that do not wish to release their source code.

dashboarding at codeplex seems nice, but it uses a non-standard way of doing UserControl: There is a control hierarchy deriving from UserControl, so Visual Studio doesn't know how to display controls in the designer. They work at run-time, but it is hard to tweak them in Visual Studio.

Comment: In response to Dale Barnard, the wpfgauge at codeplex appears now to be BSD.

Comment: Thanks, @Dave Dawkins, for pointing out the change in license!