# Compass/Aircraft Gauge Control

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-c++, activex

Can anyone suggest some beautiful Gauge Controls that can works under VC/.Net environment, it is best to contain lot of styles, e.g. compass, aircraft instrument etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499902/any-wpf-gauge-controls-that-are-open-source

Comment: Do you want WinForms or WPF?  Open source, free to use, or is payware ok?  "Recommend me a library" questions aren't the best since the answers change over time (they're quite similar to shopping questions banned from SU).

Answer (score 1):

I am fully aware that [this project](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2010/08/java-swing-component-library.html) doesn't fit your bill as it's Java-Swing based, but these gauges are so beautiful and well-assorted, they can serve as an inspiration should you fail to use ready-to-use components.

The same author also made a [HTML5 Canvas based version](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2011/06/html5-canvas-update.html) (impressive demo [here](http://idisk.mac.com/han.solo-Public/SteelSeries/SteelSeries.html)) of these components.

Updated link to the demo: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/84552/SteelSeries/SteelSeries.html

Maybe this helps.